# Java / Implementing LinkedList

Tags: java, reference, insert, linked-list

I'm trying to implement a Linked List by embedding classes but I have problem with inserting an element into the list.
Why doesn't my solution work? I can return an element by this way using get(), but I can't insert one once my iterator reached the destination.

```
public void insert(int index, int value) {

    Node iterator = head;

    int i=0;
    while(iterator != null) {

        if(i++ == index) {

            iterator = new Node(value, iterator);
            return;

        } else {

            iterator = iterator.next;

        }   

    }       

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `iterator` is a temporary variable in this function call. When you reassign its reference to another object, you're actually not modifying the Linked-List outside of this function scope. You should instead use the following

```
if(i++ == index) {
    iterator.next = new Node(value, iterator);
    return;
}
```

Note the `iterator.next` instead of just reassigning the iterator.
This way you will be modifying the Linked-List as you intend to, instead of just modifying a local variable that will fall out of scope once the function call ends.

Comment: It does not work. For instance i add 1 2 3 4 , and insert(1, 10) my output is: 1, 2, 10, 2, 10, 2 .....

Comment: Are you making multiple calls? or just a single `insert` call and results in multiple 2s and 10s.
Since the modification adds to iterator.next, you might want to change the if statement from `if(i++ == index)` to `if(++i == index)`

Comment: I use "gets" like get(0...n) and only one insert()

Comment: Can you post what's in the LInkedList before and after the `insert(1, 10)` call?

Comment: Should i insert the whole code with 123 lines? Sorry but i just joined the community.

Comment: One thing you have to be careful of is to stitch back the latter nodes after you modify the `next` field of the Node. i.e. when you add (1) into (0) -> (2), you need to make sure modify `next` of (1) to (1) -> (2) before you modify `next` of (0) to (0) -> (1). So you don't lose any of the tail nodes.

Either way, the original problem of modifying the local variable `iterator` is the most difficult part conceptually.

Comment: By the way, you should try to use standard libraries as much as you can to avoid bugs. Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html
You can use any type of Object as nodes inside the Java LinkedList Collection.

.. and of course, welcome to the community :)

Comment: Upvoting an `answer` that resolved the problem is always good etiquette XD

Comment: Could you tell me another way to reach to my linkedlist from the function? I managed to do it with the first way but now im trying to implement a PriorityQueue where i must refer to the very first element, and not first.next ! I promise i will upvote;)

Comment: As long as you have the reference to the actual object (LinkedList, PriorityQueue, HashMap) you can use the reference to go into the object and modify it. The key point is that you can't modify the local reference to the object.
`iterator` is a local reference to the object, changing the reference doesn't change the object
`iterator.next` or in fact `iterator.{anything}` actually modified the object, and not the local reference. Which is exactly what you want :)

Comment: @BenyBosko Did things also work out for the PriorityQueue?

Comment: I have a minor problem with adding element to the tail of the Queue. In this case my iterator is null via iterator.next, and i cant overwrite any variable which solved the things before. How should i modify the object and not the temporary variable (iterator) ?